# Access - Using a Form Button To Set Field Value

Tags: ms-access, button, field

I'd like to create a 'colour wheel' in Access, where the user is shown a range of colours in a form and selecting any colour places the colour name in a table field.

I thought of doing this through creating many buttons, each one a different colour. So when the user clicks on a blue button (for example), the field titled 'Colour' in the 'Preference' table is set to 'Blue'.

I've set the `On Click` property for this button to `=[Colour].[Value]="Blue"`, however this has not worked. I'd appreciate some guidance on where I've gone wrong and how to correct this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have some code in the event - like:

```
Me![YourTableColourField].Value = "Blue"
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, if the field is set as Number format then I wouldn't be able to enter text using inverted commas and would have to enter a number? In other words, is there any way to enter text if the field is Number format?

Comment: No.  Why is your field for colors numeric?

Answer (score 0):

`On Click` is an Event.  Therefore, it should look something like this:

```
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "UPDATE Preferences SET Colour = XXX"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Replace the XXX with whatever number you like.  If the table has more than one entry then you're going to need a WHERE statement in there that indicates which record should be updated (this is usually done by using some type of ID field to distinguish records).